# One to One relationship with Id in both tables. Possible or should avoided?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using MS SQL I created 3 tables: Reviews, Members and Workers.

Each Member or Worker has only 1 Review. And a Review can only be from 1 Member or 1 Worker.

So I created 1 to 1 relationship between Reviews and Members and Reviews and Workers.

```
CREATE TABLE Reviews (
  ReviewId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Members (
  ReviewId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ReviewId),
    FOREIGN KEY (ReviewId) REFERENCES Reviews(ReviewId)
);

CREATE TABLE Workers (
  ReviewId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ReviewId),
    FOREIGN KEY (ReviewId) REFERENCES Reviews(ReviewId)
);
```

**Question**

I would like to get Members or Workers by each one Id and not by a ReviewId.

Can an Identity column be added to Workers and Members (WorkerId and MemberId)?

Shouldn't this column be a PK to be indexed and faster to get records?

Can WorkerId / MemberId be a PK when ReviewId is already a PK for the 1 to 1 relation?

Comment: If there is a 1 to 1 relationship between all of these, why not just have a single table?

Comment: What do you mean? I cannot place Workers and Members in a single table as they will have different columns ...

Comment: You would have all the columns in the single table. When you have a one to one relation (between 3 tables here) it's very unlikely you actually need 3 when 1 can do the job; as it seems here.

Comment: I can't have only one table as Workers and Members will have not only different columns but also different relations to other tables ... And Reviews will all have relations to other tables ...

Comment: This sounds like you're saying there *isn't* a one to one relationship... If a Worker can only be related to one Member, and one Member can only be related to one Worked, and both of those can be only related to one review, then surely a single table, not three, is the correct design choice. I feel you've overly simplified the problem here.

Comment: You say "a Worker can be only related to one Member" ... But Workers and Members don't relate ... Workers relate to Reviews and Members relate to Reviews. Not between Worker and Member.

Comment: That isn't the impression you gave in your question, @Miguel; there's the problem.

Comment: I wrote "So I created 1 to 1 relationship between Reviews and Members and Reviews and Workers." ... I did not mention a relation between Members and Workers. But I hope it is clear now with my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a table ReviewOrigin (two rows Worker and Member). Review table can have ReviewID, ReviewOriginID and ReviewerID. ReviewerID is either MemberID or WorkerID.

Enforce a composite uniquess on ReviewOriginID and ReviwerID.

The IDs in all these tables can be IDENTITY. You need to index the columns based on your query needs. Start with PK of IDENTITY columns and created needed composite NCs on all IDs columns in Review table.